# SQL Server @@rowcount before limit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a project where I need to get the total row count before the limited results. I have this working in mysql, but I need it to work in SQL Server as well.

I know I can figure this out with some more time, but I'm tired and I have a lot of other work I need to be doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my query:

```
WITH filter 
     AS (SELECT "order"."amount", 
                "order"."id", 
                "status", 
                "priority", 
                "poNum", 
                "ip", 
                "customer"                                     AS 'cID', 
                "customer"."firstName", 
                "customer"."lastName", 
                "date", 
                "shippingMethod", 
                "site" + ':' + Isnull("admin", '')             AS "site", 
                "displayedCurrency", 
                "address"."country", 
                Isnull((SELECT COUNT("rma"."id") 
                        FROM   "rma" 
                        WHERE  "rma"."order" = "order"."id" 
                        GROUP  BY "rma"."order"), 0)           AS rma, 
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "order"."id" DESC) AS rownum, 
                Isnull((SELECT COUNT("order") 
                        FROM   order_comment 
                        WHERE  "order" = "order"."id" 
                        GROUP  BY "order"), 0)                 AS COMMENT 
         FROM   "order" 
                LEFT JOIN "customer" 
                  ON "customer"."id" = "order"."customer" 
                LEFT JOIN "address" 
                  ON "address"."id" = "order"."sAddress") 
SELECT * 
FROM   "filter" 
WHERE  "rownum" BETWEEN 0 AND 10 
ORDER  BY filter."id" DESC 

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS 'cnt'
```

Comment: @sll Thank you for formatting it.

Comment: use http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm fo future posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered it myself.

I used the [over() clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) after count(*). I don't know if that is the best solution, but it worked for me.

```
WITH filter 
     AS (SELECT count(*) over() AS 'cnt',
                "order"."amount", 
                "order"."id", 
                "status", 
                "priority", 
                "poNum", 
                "ip", 
                "customer"                                     AS 'cID', 
                "customer"."firstName", 
                "customer"."lastName", 
                "date", 
                "shippingMethod", 
                "site" + ':' + Isnull("admin", '')             AS "site", 
                "displayedCurrency", 
                "address"."country", 
                Isnull((SELECT COUNT("rma"."id") 
                        FROM   "rma" 
                        WHERE  "rma"."order" = "order"."id" 
                        GROUP  BY "rma"."order"), 0)           AS rma, 
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "order"."id" DESC) AS rownum, 
                Isnull((SELECT COUNT("order") 
                        FROM   order_comment 
                        WHERE  "order" = "order"."id" 
                        GROUP  BY "order"), 0)                 AS COMMENT 
         FROM   "order" 
                LEFT JOIN "customer" 
                  ON "customer"."id" = "order"."customer" 
                LEFT JOIN "address" 
                  ON "address"."id" = "order"."sAddress") 
SELECT * 
FROM   "filter" 
WHERE  "rownum" BETWEEN 0 AND 10 
ORDER  BY filter."id" DESC
```

Comment: Please explain a bit about your answer for passersby